# How to prevent creating a new record from dashboard grid?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dashboard, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a dashboard that holds a few views (grids) I need to disable/hide the **add +** button from some grids, is there an option to controlling dashboard some of the grids will have the **add +** button and some will not?

Comment: Are you okay with removing the button from all subgrids related to the same entity, or is this specific to the dashboard ?

Comment: @Alex thanks I'm not ok with removing from all grids so I will leave add button in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity ribbon buttons can be customized for Main grid, Subgrid & Form. There are different `(+) Add New` buttons available from Main grid, Associated grid, Subgrid and Form. They can be customized/hide/delete from Ribbon workbench, or custom script action can also be applied to return boolean values for Enable/Display rules for hiding them.

Views in Dashboard does not have a separate Ribbon, they use either Main grid or subgrid ribbon only. When you hide it - it will be hidden from all the views in all the places, for example: wherever subgrid is embedded. So there is no special way to hide/remove only from Dashboard view.

If the dashboard is containing views from same entity - you cannot hide for some views & show from some. Also there is no form scripting for Dashboard to write custom javascript, even if we write some script in Dashboard ribbon button, they cannot access the components in any supported way.